# Spinner in AlertDialog Box - Android

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-alertdialog, android-inflate

Here's the code I have so far.

**playername.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:text="Choose the server: "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/serverspinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/servers_array">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/insert_name"
    android:maxLines="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
....
public void playerStats(final View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View inflator = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playername, null);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.serverspinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(v.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.servers_array));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    builder.setView(inflator)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.done, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String server = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    EditText userNameText = (EditText) inflator.findViewById(R.id.username);
                    String userName = userNameText.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayerStats.class);
                    intent.putExtra("nume",userName);
                    intent.putExtra("sever",server);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                              })
    ;
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

In my layout.xml (not shown because it's not important), I have a button that starts "playerStats" function from my activity which brings up an alertdialog window where I give some input. In this window, I have a spinner and an edittext and I can't get the spinner to work properly (to work properly means to be able to get the string selected from the array - servers_array).

From the line marked in MainActivity, I get this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: it could be because of without setContaint use dialog instead of AlertDialog and set custom view then

Comment: Are you getting array properly in your adapter??

Comment: @VivekMishra Yes, I have made a toast to "print" the first element of the array and it is working; I think the problem is from my spinner (I might be wrong though)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it to work.

Replace this line:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.serverspinner);
```

With this one:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) inflator.findViewById(R.id.serverspinner);
```